# splitting string by spaces and new lines

Tags: java

I'm trying to split a string into an array. This should be fine as `str.split(" ")` should work fine, however the string is actually in the form of `"xyz 100b\nabc 200b\ndef 400b"`. I'm wondering what the best way to handle this is. I also need to return 4 strings in the format they gave. Below is how I'm trying it now, but it's not splitting the array up correctly. My goal is to get the array split to `["xyz", "100b", "abc", "200b", "def", "400b"]`

```
public static String solution(String words){
    String array[] = words.split(" ");

    /*
    There's a lot of other code manipulating the array to get 4 figures in the
    end. This doesn't matter, it's just splitting the array and the return that
    is my issue
    In the end I will have 4 integers that I want to return in a similar way
    that they gave them to me.
    */

    return "answer 1" + String.valueOf(num1) + "b\n" + 
           "answer2 " + String.valueOf(num2) + "b\n" +
           "answer 3" + String.valueOf(num3) + "b\n" + 
           "answer4 " + String.valueOf(num4) + "b\n";

}
```

EDIT:

`String array [] = str.split("\n| ")` will split the array as I needed, thank you A.Oubidar

Comment: Can you update your question with the code that you have tried so far?

Comment: Sorry, I explained it quite bad, it's just the split and return I was trying to get help with. A.Oubidar actually gave me more than enough for the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope i understood your question right but if you're looking to extract the number and return them in the specific format you could go like this :

```
    // Assuming the String would be like a repetition of [word][space][number][b][\n]
    String testString = "xyz 100b\nabc 200b\ndef 400b";

    // Split by both endOfLine and space
    String[] pieces = testString.split("\n| ");

    String answer = "";

    // pair index should contain the word, impair is the integer and 'b' letter
    for (int i = 0; i < pieces.length; i++) {
        if(i % 2 != 0 ) {
            answer = answer + "answer " + ((i/2)+1) + ": " + pieces[i] + "\n";
        }
    }
    System.out.println(answer);
```

This is the value of answer after execution :

```
answer 1: 100b
answer 2: 200b
answer 3: 400b
```

Comment: It turns out it as actually just ```str.split("\n| ")``` that I was looking for, thank you for that! Sorry for making you do extra work :(

Answer (score 1):

You should put this code in the "return" instead of the one you already have:

```
    return "answer 1" + array[0] + "b\n" + 
       "answer 2 " + array[1] + "b\n" +
       "answer 3" + array[2] + "b\n" + 
       "answer 4 " + array[3] + "b\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

1. The `split()` method takes one regular expression as argument. This: `input.split("\\s+")` will split on whitespace (\s = space, + = 1 or more).
2. Your question is unclear, but if you're supposed to extract the '100', '200', etc, regular expressions are also pretty good at that. You can throw each line through a regular expression to extract the value. There are many tutorials (just google for 'java regexp example').